# Add two Integers up to 50 digits

Tags: java, arrays, integer, addition

This is the actual question:

**Write an interactive program that adds two integers of up to 50 digits each
(Represents integer as an array of digits).**

This is a homework question and the language to be used is Java. I got this far but I don't think it is even close.
1. It is not taking input more than 20 digits but have to work with 50 digits.
2. The method 'integerToDigits' is producing two arrays but i am unable to sort out how to use them and add them in the main method.
Help please.

```
package One;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long x,y;
        Long a[] = new Long[50];
        Long b[] = new Long[50];
        System.out.println("Please enter two numbers which have no more than 50 digits: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = s.nextLong();
        y = s.nextLong();
        System.out.println(x+ "and "+y);
        integerToDigits(x);
        integerToDigits(y);
    }
    public static Long[] integerToDigits(Long n){
        Long digits[] = new Long[50];
        Long temp = n;
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            digits[49-i] = temp % 10;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        return digits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Your question is very vague which will result in closing it.

Comment: Can't you handle that using String and then converting into BigInteger???

Comment: @shekharsuman I tried BigInteger but at the end when the temp variable  is being divided by 10 it shows an error that one is BigInteger and the other one is int.

Comment: @StephenFrancis did you try with `tempBigInteger = tempBigInteger.divide(BigInteger.TEN)`?

Comment: Doesn't this stipulation: `Represents integer as an array of digits` mean that the use of `BigInteger` is not allowed?

Comment: @BackSlash Yes, that will work with the division but not in the previous line to get the remainder.

Comment: @StephenFrancis `digits[49-i] = tempBigInteger.mod(BigInteger.TEN).longValue();`?

Comment: @BackSlash longValue is a Long type and isn't compatible with BigInteger.

Comment: @StephenFrancis but `digits` is a `long` array, so you won't have issues...

Comment: you're reading 2 longs and convert them the arrays of longs without doing anything more. The way you store each digit in a long is extremely inefficient and the way you convert isn't good either since you always looping 50 times

Comment: I think homework should be attempted by yourself. Not crowdsourced. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not taking input more than 20 digits but have to work with 50 digits.

This is because you're using `x = s.nextLong()` which is trying to convert the input to a `long`. The maximum long value is `9223372036854775807` which is nowhere near 50 digits. You'll need to get the input as a String and then covert that to your `int[]`

> The method 'integerToDigits' is producing two arrays, but I am unable to sort out how to use them and add them in the main method.

In terms of adding up the arrays of digits, you can use the same process we learn very early on in school.

- Add the units, then carry over any tens.
- Add the tens and carry over any hundreds.
- Add the hundreds and carry over any thousands.
- ...

This process can be iterated adding each order of magnitude with the carry over from the previous one.

Hopefully those tips give you a way to solve your problem.

If you do want a solution, [I've produced one here](https://ideone.com/IU1Yes) that seems to work as you require. (Although not in ideone apparently)

Comment: Thank you so much... I'll try it and then compare it with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If "Represents integer as an array of digits" is a suggestion and not a requirement a solution using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) would look something like:

```
// read numbers from input
// store first value as String "firstNumber"
// store second value as String "secondNumber"

BigInteger a = new BigInteger(firstNumber); 
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(secondNumber);
BigInteger result = a.add(b);
System.out.println("Result is " + result.toString());
```

If "Represents integer as an array of digits" is a requirement, well, then it's a silly assignment :) No one would store an integer like that. Worst case, I'd store it as a String if BigInteger was not allowed.

Comment: Thank you but it is compulsory to represent them as arrays